# Which Archimate element should I use to model an Azure tenant?

Tags: archimate

I've looked in the official documentation and I've search for examples but I'm still not sure which element to use to show an Azure tenant. I want my diagram to show two Azure tenants, our own one, and a SaaS suppliers tenant.

Comment: I would go for a `Facility` element, but it can differ on what message you want to bring accross..

Comment: @oɔɯǝɹ thanks. If you make you're answer an official answer, as opposed to a comment, then I can mark this question as answered.